# Switch between DataContext from View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC Application which is using 2 different data storages. I created 2 different Context Clases for each connection. I've texted individually and both are working great

Context 1:

```
public class DbContextA : DbContext
{
    public DbContextA ()
        : base("name=DbContextA ")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
}
```

Context 2:

```
public class DbContextB : DbContext
{
    public DbContextB ()
        : base("name=DbContextB ")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to switch between both context from the view. For do that I created a DropDownList in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Please select the data storage mode:</p>
    <div>
        <select id="StorageTypes" name="StorageTypes">
            <option value="1">Storage 1</option>
            <option value="2">Storage 2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Accept" />
    </div>
}
```

But I don't know how to make ir work as I spected, I've tried from the controller as follow:

```
    private DbContextA db1 = new DbContextA();
    private DbContextB db2 = new DbContextB();
    private string selStorageValue;

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(ViewData["Context"] != null)
        {
            if (ViewData["Context"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                var context = db1;
                return View(context.Productos.ToList());
            }
            else if (ViewData["Context"].ToString() == "2")
            {
                var context = db2;
                return View(context.Productos.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                var context = db1;
                return View(context.Productos.ToList());
            }
        } else
        {
            var context = db1;
            return View(context.Productos.ToList());
        }

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        selStorageValue = form["StorageTypes"].ToString();
        ViewData["Context"] = selStorageValue;

        return View("Index");
    }
```

But I don't know how to make it. I Will apreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
        {
            private DbContextA db1 = new DbContextA();
            private DbContextB db2 = new DbContextB();
            string selStorageValue = form["StorageTypes"];
        // Assuming selStorageValue has some value.
            ViewBag.Productos = null;
            if (selStorageValue != null)
            {
                if(selStorageValue.ToString()=="1"){
                    ViewBag.Productos=db1.Productos.ToList();

                }
                else if(selStorageValue.ToString()=="2"){
                    ViewBag.Productos=db2.Productos.ToList();

                }
            }
            else{
                 ViewBag.Productos=db1.Productos.ToList();

            }
            return View(); //View must be binded

       }
```

**View**

```
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Title";
       Layout = " layout File address";
       List<Producto> ProductoList = (List<Producto>)ViewBag.Productos;
     }
```

Now You have Productos list in view, Now use the way you wish to implement it in your view.
For example to Create a select box

```
<div id="someId">
  @Html.DropDownList("Productos", 
                     new SelectList
                     (
                       ProductoList, "ProductoId", "ProductoName"
                     ), 
                     new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba!

Comment: i don't know what u said, but thanks anyway, happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you're doing things the way you are or what the business problem you're trying to solve is, I find that knowing a bit of the background helps us provide better help.

But as far as your question, I would suggest you try **breaking down the problem into tiny little bits**. When you debug the `Index()` action, do you get anything in `ViewData["Context"]`? If not, then that's your **first small problem**. Fix that first.

Once you've overcome that one, create the next small problem.